# Apache Spark Structured Streaming (DataStreamWriter) write to Hive table

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql

I am looking to use Spark Structured streaming to read data from Kafka and process it and write to Hive table.

```
 val spark = SparkSession
   .builder
   .appName("Kafka Test")
   .config("spark.sql.streaming.metricsEnabled", true)
   .config("spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled", "true")
   .enableHiveSupport()
   .getOrCreate()

val events = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "xxxxxxx")
  .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
  .option("subscribe", "yyyyyy")
  .load


val data = events.select(.....some columns...)

data.writeStream
  .format("parquet")
  .option("compression", "snappy")
  .outputMode("append")
  .partitionBy("ds")
  .option("path", "maprfs:/xxxxxxx")
  .start()
  .awaitTermination()
```

This does create a parquet files, however how do I change this to mimic something like, so that it writes into table format which can be read from hive or spark-sql using (select * from)

```
data.write.format("parquet").option("compression", "snappy").mode("append").partitionBy("ds").saveAsTable("xxxxxx")
```

Comment: Have you considered using Kafka Connect for this purpose? It's a lot simpler.

Comment: @RobinMoffatt We do lot of transformation and filtering of the message from Kafka, do you think Kafka connect will be better option for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at [Kafka Connect for writing the data to HDFS](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-hdfs/docs/hdfs_connector.html#quickstart). It is open source and available [standalone](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs/) or as part of [Confluent Platform](https://www.confluent.io/download/).

For filtering and transforming the data you could use [Kafka Streams](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/), or [KSQL](https://www.confluent.io/blog/ksql-open-source-streaming-sql-for-apache-kafka/). KSQL runs on top of Kafka Streams, and gives you a very simple way to join data, filter it, and build aggregations.

Here's an example of doing aggregations of streams of data in KSQL

```
SELECT PAGE_ID,COUNT(*) FROM PAGE_CLICKS WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 1 HOUR) GROUP BY PAGE_ID
```

See KSQL in action in [this blog](https://www.confluent.io/blog/using-ksql-to-analyse-query-and-transform-data-in-kafka). You might also be interested in [this talk](https://speakerdeck.com/rmoff/look-ma-no-code-building-streaming-data-pipelines-with-apache-kafka) about building streaming data pipelines with these components